# Как множество страницы перенаправить на одну?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, nginx, редирект

У меня новости со старого сайта начинаются с 1 и заканчиваются 53

news/details/1
**по**
news/details/53

Как их всех перенаправить с 301 редиректом на главный раздел news

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=nginx-redirects), силами nginx

Comment: И [здесь](https://web-optimizator.com/301-redirekt-htaccess/) еще

я делал простым header -ом , но страниц было мало))